# Amazon MWS PHP-API Access and Print Out Packing List

Tags: php, amazon-mws

How do I use Amazon MWS with PHP to access and print out packing lists? What is the process, and if possible what are the steps? Examples would be helpful.

Comment: Are you talking about the same packing slips that you print from the sellercentral control panel?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're talking about MWS and "packing lists", I assume the following to be true:

- You are an Amazon Seller
- You are sending out packages yourself (MFN / merchant fulfillment), and not using AFN / FBA (Fulfillment by Amazon)

To create packing lists, you will roughly have to do the following:

1. Fetch the "OrderReport" from the Amazon MWS Servers. The returned XML will contain details for your all outstanding orders including: shipping address, quantities, SKUs and product names.
2. Confirm the reception of those orders through the "OrderAcknowledgment" API call
3. Use above data to create pretty HTML files, images, PDF files or whatever else that can be printed as packing lists

While you're at it, you may want to look at the "OrderFulfillment" call. This lets Amazon know that you've actually shipped.
The sample PHP code you linked should help you with steps 1 and 2.

(for future reference: sample client code in PHP,C# and Java is available at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ . Follow the API documentation links to get current versions)

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question because of the use of packing lists.

Amazon makes labels available, but the labels are used to differentiate between multiple sellers of the same SKU, and is not a packing list in and of itself. Amazon generates their own packing list when an order is placed for AFN orders, and MFN orders are send to you for processing via your own process.

However, assuming you are looking for the Amazon labels I took a quick look through all the API's and did not see any information on printing them. As far as I know this is only available through seller central, however if any API does that functionality it would be the feeds API.

I would suggest creating an account on https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=35 and asking the folks there - several Amazon Employee's monitor that forum and Oneida Books is the resident guru and can pretty much answer anything API related.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. As for the question, it was more in line, with using Amazon MWS's php-api to access that page or function to make those packing slips, then copy the packing-list generated as a .jpg, so I can store it in a database and in turn make them available to a retailer instantly. As that seems a more likely hook for the answer I seek, I'll take up your advice on Amazon's seller central forum and see if they have an answer, or another way entirely in which to access that data. Thanks.